# Sandbox paypal- lightbox does not load

Tags: paypal, lightbox, sandbox

Beginning Wednesday, March 27th, we encountered a problem testing PAY transactions in the Sandbox Adaptive Payment (Classic API) environment. Our last successful test was on Tuesday March 26th. We made no code or environment changes that would have affected our sandbox test transactions during that timeframe.

The problem we are experiencing is that the PayPal lightbox will not load after our application contacts the sandbox Adaptive Payment environment. At the point we try to invoke the lightbox, we have obtained a paykey. You can see the URL we are contacting, and a paykey value, in the screenshots of the error consoles in Firefox and Chrome attached.

The browser error console shows "404 – not found" error when we send a request to PayPal with a paykey. There are no other javascript errors on the page other than those generated by the request to Paypal. Is the "404 – not found" error related to the PayKey value we got back from the sandbox on the initial request? If so, why are the Paykeys suddenly not valid, when they were fine before?

The App ID we are using for the Adaptive Payment sandbox is: APP-80W284485P519543T  Is this the correct App ID for the "new" sandbox environment?

We are using  the UserID, password and signature from a verified US Business account set up in the Classic API sandbox.

```
<form id="lightbox_form"        action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay" target="PPDGFrame">
<input id="type" type="hidden" name="expType" value="lightbox">
<input id="type" name="autoredirectondone" type="hidden">
<input type="hidden" name="paykey" id="paykey" value="[paykey is inserted here]">
<input name="submit_order" id="submit_order" type="submit" class="common_input_button" value="Submit Order">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js">
</script>

<script>
var dgFlow = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({ trigger: 'submit_order' });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form action is pointing to an old URL.
The new URL for sandbox Adaptive Payments is: 
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay

See: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/